# SQL: Find longest common string between multiple rows

Tags: python, sql, string, amazon-redshift

This question is based on [SQL: Find longest common string between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315934/sql-find-longest-common-string-between-rows) that I asked, but I didn't explain it clearly so I will try again.
I have the table t1:

```
Col1   |   Col2
-------|----------------
 1     | THE APPLE 123
 1     | BEST THE APPLE
 1     | THE APPLE 5/89
 2     | BEST TASTY BANANAS
 2     | BEST TASTY BANANAS 42/7
 2     | THE BEST TASTY BANANAS
```

I want t2:

```
Col1    |  Col2
-----------------------------
 1      |  THE APPLE
 2      | BEST TASTY BANANAS
```

My entire table has 30,000 records. At no point do I have to compare more than 21 records. Col2 is varchar(100). I am using Redshift. I realise its a difficult problem, any way of taking the data out of redshift and using some sort of fuzzystring match in say Python or something? Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and how did your attempt fail?

Comment: You promise to explain it clearly, but you don't explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

The processing that you want to do is extremely difficult in SQL.  You would have to write your own aggregation function to handle string manipulations that are expensive and not obvious.

You can do the work in Python, but it is still about the same amount of work.

For SQL, the issue is the format of the data.  You really need one row per character or word in order to find the longest matching substring.  Even with this representation, it would be difficult, particularly for long strings.  One application where I could see this being useful is in genomics, and the string encodings might be tens or hundreds of thousands of characters long.

My advice is to think about how to solve this problem algorithmically, in a language such as Python or Java.  If you search, there may be a built-in library somewhere that does this.  However, I am skeptical.  You might find a routine for two strings, but for multiple strings the problem is rather more difficult.